# Javascript Animation + error with redirect to URL

Tags: javascript, redirect

My animation works, but my redirect does not.

Do you know what the problem is here:

```
$('#bounce').on('click', function(e) {
  marker.animateBounce();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
  }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: Hi Rafal, can you provide a link with the (semi) working code? It's really hard to help you just looking at the snippet. I'd like to see the `animateBounce` code working. There's likely an error there preventing the timeout from firing.

Comment: This code is fine. Either 1) there's an error in your `animateBounce` method, or 2)  .. is this being executed within an `<iframe>`?

Comment: The insecure `http` generates a mixed content error preventing the redirect.

Comment: How i can do redirect after this marker.animateBounce(); ?

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a little example that "works", but only after making the redirect `URL` secure, using `https`. It works insofar as it attempts to make the redirect, but reports that the link you provided is not secure. If you change the URL back to the `http` prefix, the redirect will fail and generate an error.

```js
function marker(){};

marker.prototype.animateBounce = function () {
  document.querySelector('.circle').classList.add('bounce');
}

var marker = new marker();

$('#bounce').on('click', function(e) {
  marker.animateBounce();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://gameofpoland.pl/prace-tymczasowe';
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-.5em);
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.circle.bounce {
  animation: 1s alternate infinite bounce;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bounce">button</button><br><br>
<div class="circle"></div>
```